# run-time break error with pointer to a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

C++ - This program gives a run-time break error at line 2.

```
char * ptr = "hello";
(*ptr)++;            // should increment 'h' to 'i'
cout<<ptr<<endl;     // should display 'iello'
```

Unhandled exception at 0x004114b0 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00417830.

Any idea why it is giving this error? Whereas if I run the following code, it works absolutely fine.

```
char arr[] = "hello";
char * ptr = arr;
(*ptr)++;           // increments 'h' to 'i'
cout<<ptr<<endl;    // displays 'iello'
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to change read-only memory. There is a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html) which is adequate, even if this is a C++ question.

Basically when saying `char *ptr = "hello"` the compiler is free to place "hello" in read-only 
memory so it's not safe to try to write to it.

Another [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html) might be useful:

> What is the difference between these initializations?
>
> ```
> char a[] = "string literal";
> char *p  = "string literal";
> ```

Comment: They way I am changing it in the second portion of code, isn't that also read-only memory?

Comment: @Saad Read the link I provided, it explains that too :-)

Comment: thanks! much appreciated. But why does compiler treats *ptr++ and ptr++ the same way? Its only when I place brackets around (*ptr)++ that it behaves differently.

Comment: @Saad Look for "operator precedence" in your book.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare char * ptr = "hello";
it means ptr is pointing to a constant string

when you say ptr++ ,
You are trying to change the base address  which is not correct

Comment: ptr++ or *ptr++ doesnt give any error.
But when I place quotes, (*ptr)++ then it gives an error. 
I am not trying to change the base address, rather modifying the contents located on that address.

Comment: While it's true that ptr is pointing to a constant string, `ptr++` would be perfectly valid (moving the pointer on). However, the question involves `(*ptr)++` - incrementing the value currently pointed to.

Comment: as @cnicutar pointed out char * ptr = "hello"; instructs the compiler that ptr is pointing to a constant string . whereas in case of char arr[] = "hello";
char * ptr = arr;   ptr is a non const pointer